# C# using MySql and MariaDB

Tags: c#, mysql, apache, xampp, mariadb

I'm an IT student from Switzerland and have some experience in C# and Java. Now in school, we have some lessons about MySql, using the XAMPP-package. I had the idea, to make a tool in C# using MySql to use Databases on MariaDB. I've searched many times in Google and on Stack Overflow, but I didn't find any solution, that works. Using Linq isn't also the same thing, so I hoped, you may help me.

```
string connection = "server=localhost;database=example_bankdb;uid=root;password=";
var dbConn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(connection);

try
{
    dbConn.Open();

    string s0 = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`;";
    var cmd = new MySqlCommand(s0, dbConn);
    dbConn.Close();
    Console.WriteLine("Verbindung wird hergestellt");
}
catch
{
    Console.WriteLine("Die Verbindung kann nicht hergestellt werden");
}
```

[Return of the Console, that the code run and should create a new database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krMX8.png)

[image: Return of the Console, that the code run and should create a new database]

[I've opened the database overview and saw, that the database wasn't created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3p7WH.png)

[image: I've opened the database overview and saw, that the database wasn't created]

So, here is my question, is it possible, to create and use a database from MariaDB for a C# project? And how can I manage this?

I hope, my question is formatted right and I gave enough information to solve this problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like you're executing the query. Try adding `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`

```
dbConn.Open();
s0 = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`;";
cmd = new MySqlCommand(s0, dbConn);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
dbConn.Close();
```